# Javascript: Loop through nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, foreach

I have an server response with data which has the structur as you can see in the codesnippet.
My goal is to iterate through each **consent** and add the channels

The data from the response:

```
[
  {
      "consents": [
          {
              "channels": [
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "sms",
                      "title": "SMS/MMS"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "email",
                      "title": "E-Mail"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": false,
                      "id": "phone",
                      "title": "Telefon"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": false,
                      "id": "letter",
                      "title": "Brief"
                  }
              ],
              "client": "App",
              "configId": "99df8e86-2e24-4974-80da-74f901ba6a0d",
              "date": "2018-03-08T16:03:25.753Z",
              "granted": true,
              "name": "bestandsdaten-alle-produkte",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "versionId": "bd002dcd-fee6-42f8-aafe-22d0209a0646"
          }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2018-03-08T16:03:25.778Z",
      "id": "1b9649a6-d8de-45c6-a0ae-a03cecf71cb5",
      "updatedAt": "2018-03-08T16:03:25.778Z",
      "username": "demo-app"
  },
  {
      "consents": [
          {
              "channels": [
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "sms",
                      "title": "SMS/MMS"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "email",
                      "title": "E-Mail"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "phone",
                      "title": "Telefon"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "letter",
                      "title": "Brief"
                  }
              ],
              "client": "App",
              "configId": "99df8e86-2e24-4974-80da-74f901ba6a0d",
              "date": "2018-03-08T14:51:52.188Z",
              "granted": true,
              "name": "bestandsdaten-alle-produkte",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "versionId": "bd002dcd-fee6-42f8-aafe-22d0209a0646"
          }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2018-03-08T14:51:52.208Z",
      "id": "cf550425-990e-45ef-aaee-eced95d8fa08",
      "updatedAt": "2018-03-08T14:51:52.208Z",
      "username": "demo-app"
  },
  {
      "consents": [
          {
              "channels": [
                  {
                      "granted": false,
                      "id": "sms",
                      "title": "SMS/MMS"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "email",
                      "title": "E-Mail"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": true,
                      "id": "phone",
                      "title": "Telefon"
                  },
                  {
                      "granted": false,
                      "id": "letter",
                      "title": "Brief"
                  }
              ],
              "client": "App",
              "configId": "99df8e86-2e24-4974-80da-74f901ba6a0d",
              "date": "2018-03-08T14:48:27.024Z",
              "granted": true,
              "name": "bestandsdaten-alle-produkte",
              "version": "1.0.0",
              "versionId": "bd002dcd-fee6-42f8-aafe-22d0209a0646"
          }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2018-03-08T14:48:27.054Z",
      "id": "7fc1f087-2139-4494-bad7-161b0c6231a9",
      "updatedAt": "2018-03-08T14:48:27.054Z",
      "username": "demo-app"
      },
    ]
```

The way i go is the following. But i need a way to append the channels to each Consent. Is there a way to solve this?

```
consentsList.forEach((consent, index, array) => {
      consent.consents.forEach((c) => {
        Object.keys(c).forEach((key) => {
          dd.content.push(
            {
              columns: [
                {
                  text: `${key}: `, style: 'text'
                },
                {
                  text: c[key], style: 'text'
                }
              ]
            }
          );
        });
      });
      Consents.push(consent);
      if (index !== array.length - 1) {
        dd.content.push({
          margin: [0, 0, 0, 5],
          canvas: [{
            type: 'line', x1: 0, y1: 5, x2: 595 - (2 * 40), y2: 5, lineWidth: 0.6
          }]
        });
      }
    });
```

[image]

I want to output the individual channels where channels is on the top of each entry

Comment: What is this `dd.content`?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `dd.content` comes from _pdfmake_
It is the array, which i need for generating the pdf

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I add an image in the post to see what is has to be outputted.

Comment: You can use Underscore JS , properties here.

Comment: We don't need to see your final output. We need to see the json you want. Also, see @Ele post above

Comment: "channels" in the image is empty, while you say you need to "add" channels, and that the image is what needs to be outputted

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the titles using map. And concantanate them using join like this.

```
       let value = "";
       if(key === "channels"){
          value = c[key].map(x => x.title).join(" ,");
       }      
       else {
          value = c[key];
       }
       columns: [
                {
                  text: `${key}: `, style: 'text'
                },
                {
                  text: value, style: 'text'
                }
       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a piece of code, hope this is what you're looking for. It is not optimized, try to optimize at your will

```
var a = responseData;
a.forEach(function(items) {
  var allChannels = [];
  items.consents.forEach(function(innerItems){
     innerItems.channels.forEach(function(value){
        allChannels.push(value.title);        
     })
     items.allChannels = allChannels.join();
  })
});
console.log(a);
```